Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (8.4.0). I'm using macbook M1
whenever i try to use and open MySQL Workbench i always get this warning/pop up ;Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (8.4.0).
A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0.
For MySQL Server older than 5.6, please use MySQL Workbench version 6.3.
I've been struggling for like a day now to use MySql .. i'm completely beginner with this kind of stuff
i tried to follow some yt videos but doesnt seem working

Which version of MySQL Workbench do you use?

The Workbench was expecting versions 5.6-8.0, and there is no newer Workbench version that was updated to handle 8.4.  As of today the latest Workbench version is 8.0.36.
It's OK to ignore the warning. In the dialog just check Don't show this message again, and click Continue Anyway.
